# Display the selected item, not the number

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

Django python problem: The select drop down returns the numeric value of the item. I can't figure out how to get the text value of it.

Models.py

```
profile_types = (('0', "Yadda"), ('1', "Frank and beans"), ('2', "Type"), ('3', "Placeholder"),\
                ('4', "Another"), ('5', "And another"), ('6', "aaand another"),\
                 ('7', "Another"), ('8', "Last Type"))

class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)
     profile_types = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=profile_types)
```

Forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.Form):
    profile_types = (('0', "Yadda"), ('1', "Frank and beans"), ('2', "Type"), ('3', "Placeholder"),\
                    ('4', "Another"), ('5', "And another"), ('6', "aaand another"),\
                     ('7', "Another"), ('8', "Last Type"))
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text'}) )
    about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'input-text'}), required=False)
    org_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text'}))
    org_type = forms.CharField(max_length=8, widget=forms.Select(choices=choices))
    profile_type = forms.CharField(max_length=4, widget=forms.Select(choices=choices))
```

Template:

```
<span>{{ profile.profile_type }}</span>
```

Which returns

```
  1  <-- (I'm trying to display "Frank and beans") -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model has a method `get_profile_type_display` for this very purpose: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Incidentally, if you wanted you could also search through the choices, either using `dict(profile_types)` or `[b for a,b in profile_types if a == test_value]` where `test_value` is the numeric value you are looking for.